# Laravel Default Auth not redirecting to correct path

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'm having issues with getting the built-in Laravel Auth redirecting to the correct path when the user is not logged in.

From the documentation it appears I can add the following to AuthController.php

```
    // redirect paths
    protected $redirectPath        = '/profile';
    protected $loginPath           = '/home';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/home';
```

Adding this should allow me to control where users are redirected in a variety of circumstances however none seem to have any effect.

Digging through the code I can see the auth/login route is set in middleware/authenticate.php in the handle function as per below:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

If I change the path here it works however this is surely not the best way to achieve it.

I am using Laravel 5.1.7 and have tried php artisan route:clear

Any ideas/suggestions would be fantastic.

Comment: there's no problem to change the path in auth middleware, as it is customizable as per your need

Comment: Hi @CodeRomeos -thanks for the response. I can see this but why in the docs does it state I can change the redirects in the authcontroller if none of them have any affect ... Seems like something must be wrong somewhere here...

Comment: you can create a route and name it as login and in auth middleware, you can replace 'auth/login' with your named route like ->guest(route('login'))

Answer (score 0):

Use this block of code in your controller which you want to hide from logged out user. This code will redirect any logged out user to `$loginPath` and you also can use `protected $redirectTo = 'yourDesirepath'` to redirect a user after loggin.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Or if you want you can only secure few methods. Add this line of code in your method.

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```